# Magento overwrite core block

Tags: php, magento

I need to overwrite `core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Catalog/Edit/Tab/Actions.php`

At moment I have module `Bv` and namespace `Discounts`

my `config.xml` is

```
<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <discounts>
            <class>Bv_Discounts_Model</class>
            <!--
            need to create our own resource, can't just
            use core_resource
            -->
            <resourceModel>discounts_resource</resourceModel>
        </discounts>
        <discounts_resource>
            <class>Bv_Discounts_Model_Resource</class>
            <!--<deprecatedNode>discounts_mysql4</deprecatedNode>-->
            <entities>
                <accumulative>
                    <table>bv_discounts_promo_catalog_accumulative</table>
                </accumulative>
            </entities>
        </discounts_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <discounts>
            <rewrite>
                <promo__catalog_edit_tab_actions>
                    Bv_Discounts_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Actions
                </promo__catalog_edit_tab_actions>
            </rewrite>
        </discounts>
    </blocks>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <bv_discounts before="Mage_Adminhtml">Bv_Discounts</bv_discounts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

and class

```
class Bv_Discounts_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Actions
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Actions
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = Mage::registry('current_promo_catalog_rule');

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(); ....
```

Wot's wrong?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/how-to-override-mage-checkout-block-links

and

http://www.pierrefay.com/rewrite-modify-block-magento-92

this post say that my code must work, but it's not!

---

EDIT

after changing config.xml

```
<blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions>Bv_Discounts_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Actions</promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

seems magento see my new overloaded class, when I add `die();` to `function _prepareForm()` and part of page crashed (in browser), but when I adding some functionality code - nothing happened!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance, this is wrong in config.xml

```
<blocks>
    <discounts>
        <rewrite>
            <promo__catalog_edit_tab_actions>
                Bv_Discounts_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Actions
            </promo__catalog_edit_tab_actions>
        </rewrite>
    </discounts>
</blocks>
```

It should be

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions>Bv_Discounts_Block_Promo_Catalog_Edit_Tab_Actions</promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

Comment: `<promo__catalog_edit_tab_actions>` -> `<promo_catalog_edit_tab_actions>` )))

change `discounts` to `adminhtml`, but still don't work.

Comment: Clear the cache. If it still does not work, make sure your module is loaded then check var/log for errors

Comment: it seems module working, if I add die() to `function _prepareForm()` part of page (in browser) crash, but code with I adding don't work!, wot is it?